# Approaching VPS hourly billing - how would you do it?

Tags: php, laravel, architecture

I need to implement VPS hourly billing for a personal project, and I'd like to hear from you if my approach is a good approach and/or if there's a better way of handling this. Think of a service where you rent a VM, but you only pay for the time the VM is turned on.

I planned on making a table as the following:

`id` ; `virtual_machine_id` ; `balance` ; `status (0 for off, 1 for on)` ; `timestamps`

Each time a VM is turned on, my app would add a row to this table with the above data. When the VM gets turned off, I'd take the timestamp of the last row, and add a new row with the updated accumulated balance.

Now this wouldn't give my user a precise balance of how much they're spending, as the balance only gets update until the VM is either turned on or off, so I planned on having a command scheduled to run every few minutes to update the balances.

Once the user makes a payment, another row would be added, with a balance of 0. My app then would start counting rows starting from the last row with a balance of 0. This still feels too simple to me and I feel like it should have more checks, but I'm not sure of how I could do it without overly complicating things.

I'm also not sure if that `status` row is necessary.

Does this sound like a good approach? I'd love to hear suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: What VPS service are you using? Isn't that available through the API?

Comment: Be aware some users will enjoy spinning up 100's VM's and not use them if thats your model. Then if you remove any of them, be ready for a charge back.

Comment: @Serge I'm not using a VPS service, it's a model for renting ARM single board computers for learning, the hardware is on premise and unfortunately there's no API.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thank you for the advise, my model consists of renting ARM single board computers for learning, similar to raspberry pi's. Each user is limited to spinning up to 2 nodes at the same time.